# Need to save page with selected option when click on yes button in alert box

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Here is My Updated Fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/sweety/XarqB/3/

Am getting the alert box but what i need is I need to save the page with selected option when i click on yes button in alert

```
     <form method="post" action="/echo/html/">
           <input type="hidden" name="html" value="&lt;p&gt;Your data has been  
             deleted&lt/p&gt;" />
           <select id="sel" name="sel" onchange="callMe()">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
           </select>
           </form>
          <div id="confirmBox">
               <div class="message"></div>
                  <span class="button yes">Yes</span>
                  <span class="button no">No</span>
                </div>
```

Comment: on change of selecty give the same alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html file:

```
<select id="sel" name="sel" onchange="return callMe()">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

javascript function

```
<script>
function callMe()
{
    var ans = confirm("Are You Sure To Save This Record...");
    if(ans)
    {
        //go to ur process/query page
        //return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;   
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: yes and what i need is i want to save the page with the selected option when i click on yes button in alert

Comment: no i need the alert box in that design only ok check my fiddle and if yes how can i save the page with the selected option?

Comment: tell mee where is ur coding page?? check this http://jsfiddle.net/crustyashish/Xtreu/164/

Comment: above is the snippet of my code just what i need is after clicking on yes button it have to save the page that is when i try to check this page after closing it have to show me the page with previously selected option

Comment: this is for after u click OK button it will post ur form form  http://jsfiddle.net/crustyashish/DBHEz/117/

Comment: no not this what i need is i need to save the webpage or URL after clicking on yes button so that user can see the same  webpage without selecting again

Comment: can we place window.location.href = "/some/url" but how can i show this page when user tries to open the webpage?

Comment: means if i hit "yes" then i have to navigate to other page??

Comment: u will get current URL by window.location.href and store this url in any hidden field on form so u can use it for further use..

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your Code I dont know why you have put `Submit` button in `select`.

**Js**

```
function alert(){
alert("Here you go");
}
```

**Html**

```
<select id="abc" name="abc" onchange="alert();" >
<option>This is option1</option>
<option>This is option2</option>
</select>
```